# Azure Service App, Debugging in Visual Studio: How to save content to local machine files?

Tags: azure, visual-studio, debugging, service-application

I am debugging my Service App, published in Azure, on my local machine with Visual Studio. I attached a debugger on the published .Net Core app.

[image]

It works fine and I can inspect all values and debugg all code I want.

[image: debugging]

But, I want to save some runtime values to a .TXT file on my local machine, so I can process it later. But it gives me the following error:
[image: Error]

It makes sense, since I am debugging a remote aplication, thats running on an Azure Server. But how can I overcome this? Is there a way?

I know I could save this values to a blob on Azure then download it, but if I could put directly on my local machine it would be easier (and free) for me!

Thx for help!

Comment: So just to understand, is the target path in your exception above (`C:/users/etc`) for your local machine? If I'm understanding correctly, if that pictured code is running remotely on a function / service app, it would try to save text to that path on the REMOTE machine, which, being managed, it presumably doesn't have write access to do.

Quick way of getting big error dumps off there, other than just dumping it to the console? if you have a logging API it could go there. For quick debugging you could probably also just use an emailer class and send the text dumps to yourself.

Comment: @UpQuark I am running another application, a local one, that would need to read, in real time, those files that a save with the Azure app. The email solution would have a such great delay I think.